# Android app keeps Screen on, how to let it go *OFF* against app settings?

Tags: screen, permissions

The app is one of those applications that keeps the screen on and doesn't permit it to turn off. It's killing the battery and I shouldn't have to simply manually turn the screen off constantly. Every other app simply lets the screen turn off once I stop interacting with it like a good app should.

Hence my question: Is there any setting/app/widget/button/magic wand of any kind that will let me block this application from keeping the screen on. There has to be some kind of permission I can revoke to stop it from doing this.

The phone is rooted.

Comment: Have you considered using Tasker to kill the app after a set duration?

Comment: I'd rather not do that but that IS going to be my last resort if nothing else works out.

Comment: Could you share the application details. Perhaps there's an alternative that you could use...

Comment: If it's a full wakelock you cannot do anything except uninstall the app. Killing it will make it even worse, as the wakelock is never released then. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915013/android-wake-lock-is-lock-released-on-application-paused

Answer (score 2):

In short, no, you cannot, write a review on the said app's entry on the Play store, and email the developer in question to get that to be made optional via settings within the app itself.

If the developer refuses to budge or dismiss the feedback, best to look for an alternative out there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a rooted phone, you can use an app such as [Permissions Denied](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stericson.permissions) to deny individual permissions to apps. Keep in mind that doing so may break application functionality that depends on the denied permission, and if the application isn't especially well written, cause it to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no, there is not a way to revoke permissions from apps at this time.
I would recommend leaving a review on the market complaining about this, or trying to find the developer's contact information.

Comment: A few months ago - WhisperCore was an app that could implement selective permission based rules. After the company was bought over by Twitter, the app has been pulled from the site and the market. Unfortunate - http://www.whispersys.com/whispercore.html

Comment: And here's another app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite  As usual, YMMV.

Comment: CM7 has an option to revoke permissions.